# Valgrind claiming I am using malloc when using new

Tags: c++, malloc, valgrind, new-operator, delete-operator

Running Valgrind against an existing codebase, I am getting a lot of "Mismatched free / delete/ delete[]" errors. Many of them are a repeat of one problem: it claims that at line XXX a `delete` operation is being used, whereas at line YYY a `malloc` operation is used. However, when I open the file that it complains about and navigate to the line numbers indicated, I find that the memory was not allocated with `malloc` but with `new`. The allocated object was an standard `ifstream` and neither `new[]` nor `delete[]` are being used.

I'm running Valgrind 3.5. Does anyone have any idea what is happening? I cannot see how this can be a real error, but I've seen some people claim that Valgrind doesn't turn up many false positives, so I want to have some confidence that this is fake before suppressing it.

Comment: I hope this is not a duplicate question. I have searched through a good number of the Valgrind questions and have not found any satisfactory answers. By the way, I cannot post the code.

Comment: @Karzak - you might not be able to post the complete real code, but nothing is stopping you from creating a small, complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: FWIW I've never seen valgrind be wrong about mismatched free/delete/delete[] before.

Comment: surely you can at least post the lines where the object is constructed and destructed? Or would you need to kill us then... ;-)

Comment: Can you paste the precise error message?

Comment: @Robᵩ I know this makes it tough, but I am not free to post that. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't provide a sample program, so this is a crystal-ball guess.

Your program provides an `operator new` but is missing an `operator delete`. The following sample program produces the same error message you are seeing:

```
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>

/*
 * Sample program that provides `operator new`, but not `operator delete`.
 */

// minimal version of new for demonstration purpose only
void* operator new(size_t numBytes) {
  return malloc(numBytes);
}

int main () {
  int *p = new int;
  delete p;
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `delete` and `operator delete(...)`? Strictly speaking, Valgrind is giving me an error about the second one.

Comment: Yes, there is, but the distinction is moot for this discussion. Run my program -- if it produces the same error message as your program does, then you have a clue. Read the source to your program, checking for the definition of `operator new` without a matching `operator delete` definition.